# Custom user input prompt (to object constructor) does not appear / appears sporadically when called from a separate thread

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, server, pyro

Have a function of the form:

```
def setup_my_object():
    my_object = My_Object()
    my_object_daemon = Pyro4.core.Daemon(port=55666)
    Pyro4.Daemon.serveSimple({my_object: "my.object"},ns = False,daemon = my_object_daemon)
```

Pyro4 library allows to access the object over the network. Because the main process creates several different objects, a separate thread is created using:

```
def main():
    threaded_object = threading.Thread(target = setup_my_object)
    threaded_object.start()
```

The object is of the form (in reality constructor is more complicated).

```
class My_Object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        name_option = input('\nDo you want to enter a name? [y/n]:\n')
        if (name_option == 'y')
            self.m_name = add_name()

    def add_name(self):
        name = input('\nPlease enter the name: \n')
        return(name)
```

The main() runs on a linux server, launched from a python console. The problem is when I launch main() the console never promts me "Do you want to enter a name?". I migh hit enter - wait for 30 seconds - nothing.  Hit enter two times - wait for 30 seconds nothing. Only when I click enter like five times (and inadvertently the sixth) it will display "Do you want to enter a name?". **What is going on and how do I avoid this, i.e. get an instant printout of "Do you want to enter a name?"?**

**Additional info:** I am not seeing this problem when launching on a Windows machine; the problem is only on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you're doing input and output to stdin/stdout from different threads. Threads and stdin/stdout don't work nicely together. Imagine 4 threads that all sit waiting in their `input`... and you press enter... what thread will see your keystroke?  That's basically random.  Same with their output; multiple threads writing to stdout can produce very weird results.

It doesn't explain the large delay though. You haven't shown all your code. What does `main()` do more?   If you replace the Pyro calls that start the daemon by some print statements, does the issue go away? Basically: figure out exactly where the cause of your issue is (what line of code) and continue from there